# Sending log to email using log4j SMTPAppender

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-boot, smtpappender

I have a Spring Boot application. I'm trying to send log to mail using SMTPAppender, but I don't get any mails. I've managed to use log4j for ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender, so I guess I have log4j added properly, and the file with log4j properties is visible.

Here is my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger = info, email, stdout, file

log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=smtp.google.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=xyz@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=abc123
log4j.appender.email.From=xyz@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.To=xyz@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.Subject=Log
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.email.EvaluatorClass=TriggerLogEvent
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%m

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=mylog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: which class are you trying to send the logs from? try adding that in the log4j properties

Comment: so SMTPAppender needs diffrent configuration than other appenders? I'll try to add a class name, but what if I want to use it in a lot of classes?

Comment: that would be my guess. otherwise how would it know which logs to email?

Comment: I wanted to send all the logs, the same text which is written to a console and a file.

Comment: hmm, then you should be good. by the way are you behind a proxy by any chance? do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: no, no errors, no proxy

Comment: did you try to remove spaces in ```log4j.rootLogger = info, email, stdout, file``` ?

Comment: No, it's not that. I wrote an answer below, if you're interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a important piece from the documentation about SMTPAppender.

> By default, an email message will be sent when an ERROR or higher severity message is appended. The triggering criteria can be modified by setting the evaluatorClass property with the name of a class implementing TriggeringEventEvaluator, setting the evaluator property with an instance of TriggeringEventEvaluator or nesting a triggeringPolicy element where the specified class implements TriggeringEventEvaluator

Also, you can't use "smtp.google.com" - it should be smtp.gmail.com
You should use GmailSMTPAppender, the details are here -
http://www.tgerm.com/2010/05/log4j-smtpappender-gmail-custom.html